# window.resize function, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that should work only at a resolution higher than 980. I wrote value if ($ (window). width ()> 980) but it does not work. More precisely works, but not correctly. When I open the site was initially in a small settlement, the script does not work as expected, but when you increase the resolution, he again does not work, what should not be. Conversely, if the initially open in high resolution, then the script is running, and if it is to reduce the window instead of what would stop working again. What am i doing wrong?

Here is the original version of the script

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.hoverfold = function (args) {
        this.each(function () {
            $(this).children('.view').each(function () {
                var $item = $(this),
                    img = $item.children('img').attr('src'),
                    struct = '<div class="slice s1">';
                struct += '<div class="slice s2">';
                struct += '<div class="slice s3">';
                struct += '<div class="slice s4">';
                struct += '<div class="slice s5">';
                struct += '</div>';
                struct += '</div>';
                struct += '</div>';
                struct += '</div>';
                struct += '</div>';

                var $struct = $(struct);                   
                $item.find('img').remove().end()
                .append($struct).find('div.slice').css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')').prepend($('<span class="overlay" ></span>'));
            });
        });
    };
})
(jQuery);
```

Here is the code that I wrote.

```
var hoverhold = function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 980) {
        (function ($) {            
            $.fn.hoverfold = function (args) {
                this.each(function () {
                    $(this).children('.view').each(function () {
                        var $item = $(this),
                            img = $item.children('img').attr('src'),
                            struct = '<div class="slice s1">';
                        struct += '<div class="slice s2">';
                        struct += '<div class="slice s3">';
                        struct += '<div class="slice s4">';
                        struct += '<div class="slice s5">';
                        struct += '</div>';
                        struct += '</div>';
                        struct += '</div>';
                        struct += '</div>';
                        struct += '</div>';

                        var $struct = $(struct);

                        $item.find('img').remove().end()
                            .append($struct).find('div.slice').css('background-image', 'url(' + img + ')').prepend($('<span class="overlay" ></span>'));
                    });
                });
            };
        })
        (jQuery);
    } else {
    }
};
hoverhold();
$(window).resize(hoverhold);
```

Comment: @Blunderfest check the last line of the code

Comment: All your code does is check the width before establishing a jQuery feature. If it's ever wider than 980 pixels, then that code will run, and nothing will ever undo that. Before that point, any attempt elsewhere in the code to *use* that jQuery add-on will throw an error; after the window is expanded it will continue to work.

Comment: What can i do to fix it?

Comment: I connected the jQuery first, but still does not work. Here is jsfiddle link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AM5z5/)